# NoSuchMethodError on Android AdMob method

Tags: java, android, xml, mobile

I don't understand what's happening. My manifest does have the proper adactivity and the app works fine locally. I'm setting up my banner ads completely in Java because they were giving me trouble in XML. I've got the latest AdMob SDK in the libs folder, I tried compiling without ProGuard to see if that was causing anything but something is happening in other devices that isn't affecting mine. I know I can cover up the problem with try/catch/finally but I'd like to fix the root cause. Users are reporting crashes with this stack trace (from the Google Play Store):

```
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.ads.AdView.setY
at org.trepix.sda.adultlesson.MainMenu.onCreate(MainMenu.java:53)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1613)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1665)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:118)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:933)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3686)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've added any external jars to reference, make sure that they are being built with the app.
In eclipse,

`right click on project --> build path --> configure build path.`

Make sure the library is checked in the Order and Export tab.

Comment: Hi I've made sure they're being built with the app, I use IntelliJ IDEA and the AdMob SDK is in the build path. It runs on my device (real device -  SGH- T769 on 4.1) and on the emulator so I'm not exactly sure what's going on.

Comment: Weird. Is it possible to test on a device that users are complaining on?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I'm going to see if the emulator will suffice while I try to find the problem.